# Quicksort, implementation on MPI

Tags: mpi

We have a quicksort algorithm implemented with MPI [quicksort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementation-of-quick-sort-using-mpi-omp-and-posix-thread/). There was a question about the code, why are we doing this

```
quicksort(chunk, 0, own_chunk_size);
 
  for(int step = 1; step < number_of_process; step = 2 * step)
  {
        if (rank_of_process % (2 * step) != 0) {
            MPI_Send(chunk, own_chunk_size, MPI_INT,
                     rank_of_process - step, 0,
                     MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            break;
        }
 
        if (rank_of_process + step < number_of_process) {
            int received_chunk_size
                = (number_of_elements
                   >= chunk_size
                          * (rank_of_process + 2 * step))
                      ? (chunk_size * step)
                      : (number_of_elements
                         - chunk_size
                               * (rank_of_process + step));
            int* chunk_received;
            chunk_received = (int*)malloc(
                received_chunk_size * sizeof(int));
            MPI_Recv(chunk_received, received_chunk_size,
                     MPI_INT, rank_of_process + step, 0,
                     MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
 
            data = merge(chunk, own_chunk_size,
                         chunk_received,
                         received_chunk_size);
 
            free(chunk);
            free(chunk_received);
            chunk = data;
            own_chunk_size
                = own_chunk_size + received_chunk_size;
        }
  }
```

Questions arose in the lines:

```
 if (rank_of_process % (2 * step) != 0)
```

and

```
if (rank_of_process + step < number_of_process)
```

Why do we need these conditions here, what do they do? And as I understand it, the sorting is implemented using the block method (where the process sorts its data block)

Comment: Just curious, who is the "we" of the first sentence? It seems like you're asking questions about your own code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does a local quicksort on each process. That's the first line, what you call the "block method". After that you have a tree-wise implementation of a merge: first you merge with step 1, that is, neighboring processes, then with step 2, step 4, et cetera. In essence this is mergesort.

Time complexity is log2(N) steps of length n, 2n, 4n, .... N/2 where N is the total number of elements and n the local, so this is essentially N. In the limit case of P=N (and therefore n=1) this makes the parallel running time N, so your speedup over the sequential complexity of Nlog(N) is log(N)=log(P) which is very far from optimal.

A correct parallel quicksort (which is very hard to code) would use a prefix operation for the initial red/white/blue split, so that step has complexity log(N), (instead of the N for your local merge), so parallel quicksort has a complexity log(N)-squared, giving a speedup P/log(P) which is a lot better than your merge sort like code.

The problem with your code is that you are not properly thinking in distributed memory terms: you start out with everything on process zero and you bring it back to process zero. Thus you are mixing a true distributed implementation and a manager/worker model. This is not optimally parallel, and so you get complexity that is closer to sequential than parallel.